# Group and merge in nested object using Lodash

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have an object data as follows:

```
[
    {
        name: "Green Tea Brownie",
        price: 60,
        amount: 10,
        seller: {
            seller_id: 124,
            seller_name: "Merry Shop"
        }      
    },
    {
        name: "Cocoa Chiffon",
        price: 20,
        amount: 50,
        seller: {
            seller_id: 124,
            seller_name: "Merry Shop"          
        }      
    },
    {
        name: "Milky Donut",
        price: 40,
        amount: 100
        seller: {
            seller_id: 421,
            seller_name: "Sweet Bakery"   
        }      
    }
]
```

So I want to group data by "seller_id" and merge top level data assigns to object name "orders", just look like as following:

```
[
    {
        seller_id: 124,
        seller_name: "Merry Shop",
        orders: [
            {
                name: "Green Tea Brownie",
                price: 60,
                amount: 10
            },
            {
                name: "Cocoa Chiffon",
                price: 20,
                amount: 50
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        seller_id: 421,
        seller_name: "Sweet Bakery",
        orders: [
            {
                name: "Milky Donut",
                price: 40,
                amount: 100
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to solve this problem several hours ago. Can anyone solve this case?

Thank you

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and what specific issue you're running into.

Comment: Please see "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

The site is not meant to provide free code given an expected input and output.

Comment: Thank you, I will read and be careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_.groupBy()` and then `_.map()` the groups to requested format:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, first, omit } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'seller.seller_id'),
  pr(map, group => ({
    ...first(group).seller,
    orders: map(group, pr(omit, 'seller'))
  }))
)

const data = [{"name":"Green Tea Brownie","price":60,"amount":10,"seller":{"seller_id":124,"seller_name":"Merry Shop"}},{"name":"Cocoa Chiffon","price":20,"amount":50,"seller":{"seller_id":124,"seller_name":"Merry Shop"}},{"name":"Milky Donut","price":40,"amount":100,"seller":{"seller_id":421,"seller_name":"Sweet Bakery"}}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do with plain JS you can use reduce

```js
const data = [{"name":"Green Tea Brownie","price":60,"amount":10,"seller":{"seller_id":124,"seller_name":"Merry Shop"}},{"name":"Cocoa Chiffon","price":20,"amount":50,"seller":{"seller_id":124,"seller_name":"Merry Shop"}},{"name":"Milky Donut","price":40,"amount":100,"seller":{"seller_id":421,"seller_name":"Sweet Bakery"}}]


const output = data.reduce((op,{name,price,amount,seller})=>{
  if(op[seller['seller_id']]){
    op[seller['seller_id']]['orders'].push({name,price,amount})
   }
  else {
    op[seller['seller_id']] = {
      seller_name: seller.seller_name,
      seller_id: seller.seller_id,
      orders: [{name,price,amount}]
    }
  }
 return op;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JS solution using **reduce**:

```js
const orders = [{
    name: "Green Tea Brownie",
    price: 60,
    amount: 10,
    seller: {
        seller_id: 124,
        seller_name: "Merry Shop"
    }      
}, {
    name: "Cocoa Chiffon",
    price: 20,
    amount: 50,
    seller: {
        seller_id: 124,
        seller_name: "Merry Shop"          
    }      
}, {
    name: "Milky Donut",
    price: 40,
    amount: 100,
    seller: {
        seller_id: 421,
        seller_name: "Sweet Bakery"   
    }      
}];

const ordersBySeller = Object.values(orders.reduce((accum, { name, price, amount, seller: { seller_id, seller_name } }) => {
  const sellerOrders = accum[seller_id] ? accum[seller_id].orders || [] : [];
  accum[seller_id] = { seller_id, seller_name, orders: [...sellerOrders, { name, price, amount } ] };
  return accum;
}, {}));

console.log(ordersBySeller);
```

Comment: Without Lodash it look more complicate but it's work, Thank you